# Wave Equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}-u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt}=u_{xx}-u,\quad0<x<\pi ,t>0\\
u(x,0)=sin(2x),\quad 0\leq x\leq \pi\\
u_t(x,0)=sin(x), \quad 0\leq x\leq \pi\\
u(0,t)=u(\pi,0)=0,\quad t\geq0
\end{cases}
$$

I am using separation of variables and getting the following ODE:

$$X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0$$

From the first boundary condition we can conclude that

$$X(0)T(t)=0\Rightarrow X(0)=0$$

For the second boundary condition we get:

$$X(\pi)T(0)=0$$

In this case we can have $T(0)=0$ and then $X(\pi)\neq 0$ so how can we solve the ODE?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but from $u(\pi,0)$ follows $X(\pi)=0$. Can you please reformulate the second question? Is not very clear.

Comment: @Albe I have rewritten the question

Comment: Are you sure it is $u(\pi, 0) = 0$ not $u(\pi, t) = 0$ as your boundary condition?

Comment: @Paul Yes, It seems like an error right? as the function is defined for $t>0$

Comment: Values at the endpoints would be fixed for a standing wave solution so $u(\pi, t) = 0$ would  sound sensible. Are you saying that you think the question has an error, rather than asking how to solve the question as you have written it? It is not clear.

Comment: It $T(0)$ = 0, you cannot satisfiy the initial condition. I didn't notice that you only have $u(\pi,0)=0$ (I misread it as $u(\pi,t)=0$)